# java for Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: java

I need JAVA 8 to run on my recent installation of
Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.   Is Java included in Ubuntu 18.04 or do I need to install it?
My computer has 2.9 GB memory, Pentium R Dual Core CPU and 314 GB hard drive.
What instructions are available for installing JAVA?

Comment: I think the default is OpenJDK so if your looking for Oracle version then you have to install!

Answer (score 0):

As @George Udosen wrote, in default Ubuntu repository is OpenJDK. If you want to have Oracle version, you can install them from this ppa: https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java/